# Converting MySQL DATETIME to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dblinq

I am using a MySQL database with [DbLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/), but there is an exception being thrown:

> "Cannot convert mysql datetime to
>   system.datetime"

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How are you casting/converting it now?

Comment: Is the MySql date a unix timestamp?

Answer (score 4):

Check for any zero date means date like **'0000-00-00'** in database;
this could be the cause of error.

Answer (score 3):

Either [cast the `MySqlDateTime` as a `DateTime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_Types_MySqlDateTime_op_Explicit.htm) or use [`mySqlDateTime.GetDateTime()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_Types_MySqlDateTime_GetDateTime.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a result set containing MySql `DateTime` values, you could use the [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method along with a delegate using [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) to create a collection of [`System.DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) values.

Here's an example, where "results" is the result of your dblinq query containing MySQL datetime values:

```
List<DateTime> dateTimes = results.ConvertAll(delegate(string time){ 
   return DateTime.Parse(time); 
});
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I was moving a column in my gridview from asp:BoundField to asp:TemplateField so had to display a date from a MySQL database explicitly.  I found, through reflection, that the collection typed the date fields as MySqlDateTime and not system.DateTime.

I added the import MySql.Data.Types statement to the code behind and the following Eval statement within a label in the context of a gridview.

Text='<%# CType(Eval("Submitted_Date"), MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime).ToString%>'

output format:  02/23/2011

Hope that helps!